# How to remove this parenthesis () from this text value (123)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove this parenthesis ()  from this text value (123) and make it as integer as I want to use this repeatedly in my code how to optimise this for math calculation
I tried with below code but it's not working 
the purpose of the () is -ve i need to replace that to -123 and -321 and then do the calculation the calc will like (-321+123) = -198 and -198 again to (198)

```js
var num1 = "(123)";
var num2 = "(321)";
value = checkIntegerValue(num1, num2);

function checkIntegerValue(num1, num2) {
  num1 = num1.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
  num2 = num2.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
  if (parseInt(num1) && parseInt(num2)) {
    return parseInt(num2 - num1);
  }
}
```

Comment: **[Works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a3npncu3/)**.. What's the problem??

Comment: This works just fine.

Comment: Just add `console.log(value);` and you will see it in working.

Comment: any  way to make the code better  because i am using this multiple times shall i use str = str.slice(1,-1);

Comment: If the code is working as expected and you want to get it reviewed, you can ask it on [CodeReview.se]. Before you do so, please see [How to ask a good CodeReview Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the purpose of the () is -ve i need to replace that to -123 and -321 and then do the calculation the calc will like   (-321+123) = -198 and -198 again to (198)

Comment: @Sumanr if the `()` means it's `-ve` (which is fairly standard), then `(123)+(321)` would be `-123 + -321` or `-444` giving `(444)` .  Why do you assert that it should be `-198`?

Comment: no not like that  the logic is  -321-(-123) so -321+123 = -198  i want final as (198)

Answer (score 0):

You can take only numbers.So except that you should remove others char by the regex `/[^\d]+/g`. `\d` indicates digits only and `^` negates. so the entire regex defined that if not a number, then replace it with empty value. e.g `''`.

```js
var num1 = "(123)";
    var num2 = "(321)";
    value = checkIntegerValue(num1,num2);
    console.log(value);

    function checkIntegerValue(num1,num2){
           num1 = num1.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
           num2 = num2.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
           if(parseInt(num1) && parseInt(num2)){
            return parseInt(num2-num1);   
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've successfully removed the `(` and `)`, but there are several problems:

- It will return `undefined` if either number is `0`, because `0` is *falsy*, and your `if` condition is checking if `parseInt` returns a falsy value for either number.
- You're converting the numbers from string to number repeatedly: Once on purpose (`parseInt(num1)`), and a second time implicitly via the `-` operator. The rules for `parseInt` and implicit conversion are different. Best to do it once on purpose.
- You're using `pareseInt` on the result, which doesn't make sense as the result is *already* a number. (If you want to remove a fractional portion of a number, don't use `parseInt`, use `Math.floor`, `Math.round`, or `Math.ceil`.)
- `parseInt` may or may not be the best way for you to ensure that you have a number, as it stops on the first invalid character. So `parseInt("123abc")` is `123`, for instance. Other options are `Number` and `parseFloat`, both of which allow floating-point. The rules for `Number` are the same as for implicit conversion. `parseFloat`, like `parseInt`, stops at the first invalid character. But `Number` and implicit conversion treat `""` as `0`. So pick your poison. :-)
- Instead of checking for a falsy value, use `isNaN` to see if the conversion from string to number failed.
- Your function is doing multiple things: It converts the numbers to integers, validates them, and then returns the result of subtracting them. Ideally, a function should have a single job.
- If the `()` are meant to mean the numbers are negative, you'll need to know whether you removed them and negate the result if so.

See comments (I've also used a function to format the result with `()` when the value is negative):

```js
test("(123)", "(321)");
test("123", "(321)");
test("123", "321");

function test(str1, str2) {
  console.log(str2 + " - " + str1 + " = " + formatNumber(checkIntegerValue(str1, str2)));
}

function convertInt(str) {
  // Trim the string
  str = str.trim();
  // Flag up if negative
  var sign = str[0] === "(" ? -1 : 1;
  // Remove ()
  str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
  // If the string is blank, return NaN
  if (!str.length) {
    return NaN;
  }
  // Otherwise, parse as number
  var num = Number(str);
  // If it's not an integer, return NaN
  if (Math.floor(num) != num) {
    return NaN;
  }
  // Apply sign and return
  return num * sign;
}

// I'd give this a name more accurately describing what it does
function checkIntegerValue(str1, str2) {
  var num1 = convertInt(str1);
  var num2 = convertInt(str2);
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return num2 - num1;
}

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num < 0 ? "(" + (-num) + ")" : String(num);
}
```

Comment: *If it's not an integer, return NaN* have you done this to check if passed string is a floating number, its invalid? If yes, I don't think this is intended.

Comment: @Rajesh: The OP's code was very much about integer values, which is why that's there. Naturally, if they want to allow numbers with fractional values, they can remove it (and change various names).

Answer (score -1):

To optimize your code:

1. Move `replace` and `parseInt` out of function
2. remove from return `parseInt()`

```js
var num1 = parseInt("(123)".replace(/\(|\)/g, ''));
var num2 = parseInt("(321)".replace(/\(|\)/g, ''));
value = checkIntegerValue(num1, num2);

function checkIntegerValue(num1, num2) {
  if (num1 && num2) {
    return num2 - num1;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Move replace and parseInt out of function"* Why? What makes repeating that better than not repeating it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since he is working with same values multiple times it's better to move repeated logic out of function. Also function naming says that elements must be integers.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests he/she's working with the **same** values multiple times. Just that he/she is repeating the same operation many times. Probably on different values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Provided code is using **same** values multiple times.

Comment: It clearly isn't. The original values (in the outer `num1` and `num2`) are used once: When passed into the function. The copies of those values (the `num1` and `num2` parameters' initial values) are used once: When `replace` is called on them. What are you referring to?

Answer (score -2):

```
function checkIntegerValue(num){
       return +num.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
}
```

should work

Comment: This will not your, because you changed original logic of function.

Answer (score -2):

You can try it

```js
var mystring = '(12345)';

var mystring= mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");

console.log(mystring);


var num1 = "(123)";
 var num2 = "(321)";
 var sum_value = checkIntegerValue(num1, num2);
 console.log(sum_value);

 function checkIntegerValue(num1, num2) {
   num1 = num1.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
   num2 = num2.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
   if (parseInt(num1) && parseInt(num2)) {
     return parseInt(parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1));
   }
 }
```

Comment: `mystring.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");` is same as `mystring.replace(/"|'|\(|\)/g, "");`

Answer (score -2):

I got the answer

```
var num1 = "(123)";
var num2 = "(321)";
checkIntegerValue(num1, num2) 

function checkIntegerValue(num1, num2) {
   if(!parseInt(num1) && num1!=""){
      num1 = "-"+num1.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
   }
   if(!parseInt(num2) && num2 !=""){ 
      num2 = '-'+num2.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
   }

   if (parseInt(num1) && parseInt(num2)) {
      return num2 - num1;
   }else{
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are overusing `parseInt`. Also why `'-'.num1.replace`?

Comment: to make  (123) to -123 yes i am using parseInt because input type is not number so only